# Passing an extension method to a method expecting a delegate. How does this work?

Tags: c#, delegates, extension-methods

So at work I was using an API that we didn't write, and one of the methods took a delegate. For one reason or another, the idea came to me that I have an extension method that fits that signature, so I was wondering if it would work. I was sure it wouldn't but much to my surprise, it did. Allow me to demonstrate:

Say I have these classes:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{

}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface 
{ 

}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string FuncMethod(this IMyInterface imy, int x)
    {
        return x.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now let's say I have a method signature somewhere that looks like this:

```
    private static void Method(Func<int, string> func)
    {

    }
```

Now my extension method (looks like it) matches that signature, but we all know that extension methods are just smoke and mirrors, so it **really doesn't** match that signature. Yet, I can safely do this:

```
var instance = new MyClass();
Method(instance.FuncMethod);
```

My question is, how does this work? What does the compiler generate for me to make this acceptable. The actual signature of the Extension method takes an instance of `IMyInterface`, but the `Func` doesn't so what's happening here for me behind the scenes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instance methods are implemented as taking hidden `this` parameter.

When you create an instance delegate from an extension method, the hidden `this` parameter is passed to the method as the first normal parameter.

[Note that this cannot be done with value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016033/extension-methods-defined-on-value-types-cannot-be-used-to-create-delegates-why).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know exactly what the compiler is doing to allow these scenarios, but the expectations seem reasonable.  Perhaps this code sample will help with grappling the concept.

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
Func<int, string> f1 = instance.FuncMethod;
Func<int, string> f2 = (i) => instance.FuncMethod(i);
Func<int, string> f3 = (i) => Extensions.FuncMethod(instance, i);
```

Comment: `Extensions.FuncMethod(instance, i)` shows how the delegate is eventually called.